# Any tool available to replace an existing Table and apply all steps

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

Let's say I have a View "A" imported in powerbi as table

Very few columns is being used in the visuals from the powerbi, so in order to reduce the refresh time and sql server load I have created a new view "B" specifically for that report

Inorder to replace A with B, now I have to do everything manually, from changing Datatype in powerbi side, changing fields in visuals

Since I have retained the same name of the columns in the new view B, Is there is any tool to achieve the above in simple manner?